# why recv() doesn't set errno if other end of socket communication is closed?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I was trying to use UDP sockets. On client I set specific time out and when I call recv(), I am checking the return value and if it it is less than 0, I am checking if errno is EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK. If the errno is not one of these 2, I am trying to reconnect the server. Now I need to determine whether the other end of the connection is closed or not. Besides checking for the return value of recv() equals to '0', do I need to check for errno? Does recv() set errno, if other end of socket is closed? If not why errno is not set?

Comment: Asking about the "other end" of a UDP socket is like asking about the "other end" of a mailbox... the packets flowing through a UDP socket can come from (or go to) many different destinations.

Comment: If you want "connections" then you want TCP or possibly SCTP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UDP does not have **connections**, and thus you cannot easily deduce whether or not the other end had closed the socket. If you need connections, you must use TCP.

However, *often* a receiver sends an ICMP reply when contacted to an UDP port that is not open; this can be signalled as a return value from `recv` or `send`; on Linux this can happen for any UDP sockets, and on BSD it seems it only applies to "connected" UDP sockets.

In any case, you cannot deduce between any of

- ICMP towards sender being filtered by firewall
- UDP towards receiver being filtered by firewall
- UDP being delivered successfully to the receiver

So I'd consider the possible signalling of UDP errors a "nice addition", but not something to rely on.

---

TCP is very much analogous to a phone call, whereas UDP is more like mailboxes. If you send a letter to a non-existent address that does not have a mail box, you *could* get your letter back 2 weeks later with a sticker saying that mail couldn't be delivered.

If you do not get your letter back then either the receiver received it, the post man stole it, it was shredded in a sorting machine, or perhaps a dog ate the letter; the only way to know it was actually successfully received would be that the receiver sent another letter back acknowledging the receipt.

Comment: Thanks Antti. In our project, we are using UDP and on client I am using recv() call to with a timeout. In some corner case, the server died and there is a monitoring agent in our systems, which will monitor the process and if any process dies, it will restarts the process. As I am checking only if return value os recv() is less than 0, I am listening on the old socket and even though server starts newly, I am not able to get the messages. Can you please suggest any idea how to fix.

Comment: @kadina: That sounds very weird. Since UDP is not a connection, a listening UDP socket should pick up anything sent to its IP and port. Are you sure that the other side didn't just forget to send to you?

Comment: @kadina: for example, a syslog daemon listening for UDP syslog messages does not need to reopen its socket. It just keeps getting messages.